# How to set username and password and send request to identity provider in simplesamlphp?

Tags: authentication, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I have created a service provider and right now I can call requireAuth() and get a wizard to select identity provider and then log in and get attributes of the user.

But I want to do this without filling forms manually. I develop mobile game app, which must login users using SAML 2.0. But I can't show browser inside Unity app.

Is there some way to send request with username & password to identity provider using SAML 2.0 and skip step where user fill in credentials manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAML requires that the username and password can only be received by an identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

More details on your setup, languages etc. would be beneficial go get some overview.

SAML communication is done via HTTP and http requests with XML formatted information. So it fully possible to write code that will do it without user special actions if that is what you need.

You can check how SAML communication is done here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#SP_Redirect_Request;_IdP_POST_Response